# Calculating maximum hourly rate?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table with the date and a value which is logged every few mins.

```
# date, turnover
'2013-09-06 08:45:15', '2.00'
'2013-09-06 08:48:15', '38.00'
'2013-09-06 08:51:15', '60.00'
'2013-09-06 08:54:15', '9.00'
'2013-09-06 08:57:15', '37.00'
```

Is there a simple mysql query I can run to find the maximum turnover rate per hour?

I was first thinking of working out the values per hour and then getting the max but then it occurred to me that it's probably not accurate to do this on from 1-2pm, 2-3pm, 3-4pm etc.

I would need to calculate the rate from every value, so if the first entry is on 00:05 then I would need to get the average from 00:05 to 01:05, then if the next reading is 00:03, then from 00:03 to 01:03 - do all of this for every value and compare?

Is there an easy way to do this in mysql/php?

Comment: I think you should stay with 1-2pm, 2-3pm, 3-4pm etc. anything else is much more complex and won't increase accuracy substantially (more likely it won't increase accuracy at all)

Comment: Good idea - it would make it much more simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume this is the table structure:

```
mysql> desc turnover;
+-------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| dts   | datetime      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| fee   | decimal(12,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I try with this:

```
SELECT date(dts), hour(dts), sum(fee) AS total
FROM turnover 
GROUP BY date(dts), hour(dts) 
ORDER BY total DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Thanks - that seems to be working. Just need to check the data :)